# What is the effect of a scratched lens?

Tags: lens, equipment-damage

I have a lens with a small but significant looking scratch near the center. But I don't see any difference in the photos. Where does the imperfection show up? How important is it to get the piece of glass replaced? (It's a Panasonic 14-45mm micro 4/3 lens).

Comment: The 2.7-meter telescope at McDonald Observatory has bullet holes in the primary mirror, which have been painted black to reduce scattered light. The optical quality is essentially unaffected. http://www.astr.ua.edu/keel/telescopes/mcdonald.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most of the time, the scratch will show up as a small and perhaps even unnoticeable amount of softening in the image. (It will largely be "outvoted" by the vast majority of the light, which is being focused properly.) In high contrast situations, though, or when the light is striking the lens directly, there may be a significant mount of flare washing out the image and reducing overall contrast.

The scratch will probably also make the lens element more fragile, so it will likely to be easier to crack that lens element if the lens is dropped or given a good bump -- that depends on the type of glass.

Fixing it isn't a critical emergency unless it interferes with the kinds of pictures you want to take, but if you plan to keep the lens for a long time, it would be a good idea to get it repaired at some point.

Comment: Also the effects are more pronounced as your aperture closes down, much like dust on the sensor.  Might not notice it at low f stops, but could at f18 or 22.

Answer (score 14):

Lens work surprisingly well with dirty or scratched front element. [Here](http://kurtmunger.com/dirty_lens_articleid35.html) is a very good article about it, someone deliberately ruined a lens to test this effect.

[image: REALLY ruined lens, we mean it]

Probably you'll see problems with lens flare, but the biggest disadvantage is the resale value, it will be more difficult to sell a scratched lens.

Comment: Yeah, I think that answer is pretty much there now, Jeff - you can stop polishing it :)

Answer (score 14):

Not as much as you'd think:

http://www.lensrentals.com/news/2008.10.30/front-element-scratches

Depends on the damage, and the aperture.  That's the reason I stopped using UV filters; I'd rather get the best IQ possible and risk damage which can be ignored or fixed if required.  Damage to your lens might affect the resale value; by the same token, as a buyer you could pick up a bargain.

Comment: Came here to post that link but you beat me to it! As you can see a small scratch will probably be insignificant.

Answer (score 5):

One point that hasn't been made is that it's pretty inexpensive to fix the front element of a lens, usually in the realm of $200. It's not a huge concern in general, but it if you are serious, it's worth getting fixed.

Comment: Keep in mind that the lens in question sells for less than $300 new...

Comment: Good point, but if the lens is a more expensive one, the amount for the front element replacement is still about the same.

Comment: I'd expect the front element for a professional grade lens to be more expensive than one for an entry level lens.
Unless of course that replacement service uses the same grade front elements for all their work in which case I'd want to know what grade. Putting a Quantaray front element on a $10.000 Nikkor isn't going to do that Nikkor much good.

Comment: Right, but the front element is usually the least expensive. It only costs a few hundred dollars to fix even on some of the top of the line glass, as I understand.

Comment: Wow, this is really making me feel better about not using any UV filters on my lenses for protection.  A UV filter, even multicoated, produces a noticeable effect in many pictures.  Given that a lens scratch usually produces no noticeable effect, and even if it does it can be replaced for a couple of hundred dollars (less than the total I've spent on filters), you're a mug if you put a filter on in general use just for protecting the lens.

Answer (score 5):

A lens can take a surprisingly large amount of damage to it before it will greatly degrade an image. In the event that a favorite irreplaceable filter has gotten a small conchoidal fracture at the edge or a scratch in it, blacken that area with a fine-pointed sharpie pen, removing (rubbing away) any excess ink outside of the scratch or fracture, and this will minimize any contrast-loss that you might get from when it is illuminated by bright light. I always keep a fine-pointed sharpie and a larger black magic-marker in my camera bag. The latter for blackening cyclone-fence wiring or other metal-grids that I might have to shoot through. Blacking any small section of fence or enclosure wire that I have to shoot around/through makes it nearly completely disappear.